# Moving between departments

Tags: company-culture, internal-transfer

I've been working at my current employer for 2 and a half years.

I started in a junior programmer position and worked there for 1 year before a new position opened up in a different department with a similar role but as a full fledged programmer, so I applied and moved there. I have currently been in this position for 1 and a half years.

I have just been told that there is a senior programmer position opening up in the department that I used to work in and that the new supervisor is very interested in getting me back aboard there.

My question is, is it ok to bounce back and forth between departments like this as long as I am progressing my career? I feel like I have a bit of an obligation to my current department even though the corporate policy is to freely move throughout the business. I don't want to be seen as someone who is non-committal, but to be able to progress to a senior position in such a short time is incredibly tempting.

I should add that this is a union job and I don't have to fear retribution for moving

Comment: In software, it is 100% ok.  It is, simply - normal.  Don't forget, the moment, the day, you get that new role, is the **best time** to move on to a new company for much more money.

Answer (score 0):

It may be *their* positions, but remember it is **YOUR** career, and nobody is looking out for you other than *you*.  I'd absolutely jump around if the opportunity is right.  I've found in my career moving positions is the only way to really get a good pay increase these days.  You have it good in that you can stay at the same company, so any benefits you're getting based on years at the company won't go away.  If they are considering you for a senior position, then you'd do well to check out the local market and make sure you know what you are worth, don't let them short-change you on the salary!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I don't consider it job hunting unless you're moving companies.  If they have a multitalented employee they can move around, you'll be more of an asset to them.  Take it, if it's what you want, and be happy with all the love and affection.